# How do u output the value that is return by a function in visual basic

Tags: function, recursion, output

[image]
I want to check whether the code is running correctly or not. the function takes in a base number and exponent and returns the result.
suppose the user input 2 as their base number and 4 as the exponent
2^4
function return 16
I want to output 16 on the screen.

I tried outputting the result inside the function but the program quit after entering the number.

Comment: Visual Basic has a built-in exponentiation operator ^, you can simply write "base^exponent" to calculate the result.

Comment: As you are using `return` and `Console`, I assume you are talking about `VB.Net`, not `VBA`, right? And you shouldn't show your code as image, write it as text (and format it as code) so that others can C&P it. That said: Simply put the return statement below the `Console.WriteLine(result)` so that the output is done before the routine is exited.

Comment: Thank you  I am sorry about posting the image as it my first time asking question here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "MsgBox" function to output stuff or you could use "Debug.Print" to write in the "Immediate" window.